# Accessing a database via server name

Tags: mysql, sql, hosting

I'm trying to access a client's database. This is their server name: 
mysql.speaktoeveryone.com

I cannot access it via the browser and I am not sure how to go about this.

Comment: This sounds like a network-type issue.

Answer (score 0):

What Language do you use? Can you give us more details and what are you doing to connect?

I have an example of a String URL Connection via JDBC to MYSSQL

```
 var address = "jdbc:sqlserver://sql5050.site4now.net;databaseName=DB_Example"
 var user = "DB_A5D54B_admin"
 var rootPwd  = "Password*"
 var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(address, user, rootPwd);
```

This is made with Google Script and works good

First, see this doc to install PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php

Example with PHP is:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Comment: Oh so this is for connecting from within the code itself? I was thinking more along the lines of connecting via something like mysql workbench. And the language is PHP, its a wordpress site.